# Can you not pass an integer into a stmt

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason i keep getting error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/cluster-sites/2/i/inactive_users.php on line 15.

I've realized it does not like the integer but i need to pass the id into the stmt.

```
<style>

table {width:1000px;border:1px solid #000;}
h1 {text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0px;}
h2 {padding:0px;margin:0px;}

</style>
<?php
session_start();
include_once'conn.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, registerdate FROM users WHERE level < 1");
$stmt->bind_param('issss', $_GET['id'], $_GET['username'], $_GET['firstname'], $_GET['lastname'], $_GET['registerdate']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userid, $username, $firstname, $lastname, $registerdate);


?>
```

This is where i am using the information from the table if i remove the id everything works but for some reason i keep getting the error when i include the id.

```
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
<fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="6"><h1>Inactive Users</h1></th>
<tr>
<td><h2>Username</h2></td>
<td><h2>Firstname</h2></td>
<td><h2>Lastname</h2></td>
<td><h2>Date Registered</h2></td>
<td><h2>Days Inactive</h2></td>
<td><h2>Activate</h2></td>

<?php 

while ($stmt->fetch()){

$today = new DateTime("now");  
$registered = new DateTime($registerdate);  
$dayspassed = date_diff($registered, $today);

 echo '<tr class="inactiveuser">
        <td>'.$username.'</td>
        <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
        <td>'.$lastname.'</td>
        <td>'.$registered->format("d-m-y").'</td>
        <td>'.$dayspassed->format("%a days").'</td>
        <td>
            <select name="dropmenu_'.$userid.'">
            <option selected>Select Action</option>
            <option value="activate">Activate User</option>
            <option value="delete">Delete User</option>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            </select>
        </td>';
}


$stmt->close();
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: There are no parameters in the select statement. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've included all my code now

Comment: You miss those question marks `?`.

Comment: what quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statements like this are used to protect your database from SQL-injections. This can only happen from user-input, which your query has none.

In other words, you have no variables or user-input in the query, so there are no parameters to bind.

---

Imagine the following query

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users");
```

There are no variables here to bind, so we can drop the `$stmt->bind_param` alltogether. If we had something like

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id=?");
```

..then we would need to use `$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id'])`, because we have a parameter to bind (the `?` in the query).

---

**Your solution**
Because you do not have any parameters to bind, and just have a `WHERE` clause with a static number, you can just drop the `bind_param`. So you basically want to prepare, execute, bind the results, fetch them.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, registerdate FROM users WHERE level < 1");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userid, $username, $firstname, $lastname, $registerdate);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    /* Do magic here */
}
$stmt->close();
```

For this purpose, you can just use `$mysqli->query()`, because there are *no user input* which can exploit it, but remember that whenever you deal with user-input, use placeholders for your queries.

**Some readingmaterial and documentation**

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

when you use bind param it sets a parameter in your prepare statement.

> Bind variables for the parameter markers in the SQL statement that was passed to mysqli_prepare().

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

you are getting this warning

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/cluster-sites/2/i/inactive_users.php on line 15

because there are no corresponding parameters in your prepare statement

Comment: now im just lost because if i remove the id everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, registerdate FROM users 
                    WHERE level < 1 
                    AND id = ? 
                    AND username= ? 
                    AND firstname = ? 
                    AND lastname = ? 
                    AND registerdate =  ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('issss', $_GET['id'], $_GET['username'], $_GET['firstname'], $_GET['lastname'], $_GET['registerdate']);
```

try like this. It will work

Comment: Ooohhhhh i understand now but why do i need all of the AND's. Fair enough if that's what it needed to work but could i have `("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level < 1")` ?

Comment: I've just put that code in and now no users are showing at all but no error either.

Comment: Yes you can. Remove bind_param.

Comment: May be it wouldn't satisfy all where conditions.